# Is it possible to create snapshot smaller than its original size on AWS? No bootable device error or Grub Error 15

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

For example I have an image its snapshot sized 20 GiB (*Total size of EBS Volumes: 20 GiB*) and it has 15 GiB free space. I want to create new image having 10 GiB from the instance.

When I do: Image => Create Image and entered 10 GiB for the volume, I do face with following error message:

> Volume size must be at least the size of the snapshot (20 GiB)

**[Q]** Is it possible to prevent this error and create an Image having smaller volume than the snapshot's EBS volume?

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

---

Please note that following two approaches that based on answers **did not work**, and the owner of the answer did not guide me further! I don't what anyone with same problem lose time with those approaches since copy paste operations takes a long time in between volumes. I would be grateful if someone guide me further.

**Approach 1:** (target volume is a single EBS volume)

I have followed following [guide](https://cloudacademy.com/blog/amazon-ebs-shink-volume/) based on the `@EFeit`'s answer, which links to: https://serverfault.com/a/718441

First I stopped the instance I want to resize. Than I have created smaller EBS volume as 5 GiB and attached it into my instance as `/dev/xvdf`. Start the instance and log onto the new instance via SSH; and did the followings:

```
sudo mkdir /source /target
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdf
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/xvdf /target
sudo e2label /dev/xvdf /
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/xvda1 /source
sudo rsync -aHAXxSP /source/ /target
sudo umount /target
sudo umount /source
```

Back in AWS Console: Stop the instance, and detach all the volumes.
Attach the new sized volume into the instance as: "`/dev/sda1`"
Start the instance, and it should boot up.

**Error message:**

[image]

**Approach 2:** (target volume is obtained from newly created smaller instance)

I have followed following [guide](https://serverfault.com/questions/673048/how-to-reduce-aws-ebs-root-volume-size/836600#836600). I have also faced with `Error 15` on the boot menu :(

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There's no simple way to do this, but I think [this tutorial](https://cloudacademy.com/blog/amazon-ebs-shink-volume/) will give you the outcome you're looking for.

Comment: On the tutorial after I create 8GiB small volume, from that can I create 8 GiB small volume snapchat? If I cannot change the snapshot size then I cannot create the image I assume due to the error message. @EFeit

Comment: Yes, you'll be able to create an 8 GiB snapshot from that new volume. If you wanted to create a new volume from that snapshot, you could create a volume 8 GiB or larger. The takeaway is that you can only create a snapshot of a volume at its current size.

Comment: I have faced with following issue: running: `sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvdg` gives following output: `mke2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015) Found a dos partition table in /dev/xvdg Proceed anyway? (y,n) y /dev/xvdg is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!` Please note that I have did everything in order that is guided on the tutorial. @EFeit

Comment: Please see my question, I have updated it. The solution did not worked for me. @EFeit.

Comment: I've been following the tutorial linked and am having exactly the same problem.

`ubuntu@:/$ sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvd'
mke2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Found a dos partition table in /dev/xvdf
Proceed anyway? (y,n) y
/dev/xvdf is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!`

I'm certain I'm trying to mkfs on the right disk as I'm using `lsblk` to see what is mounted.

Did you ever find a solution?

@Avatar

Comment: @Michael no mate I have give up. I created smaller disk and install everything from scratch.

Comment: Arghhh, that's not what I wanted to hear.  
I don't have that option, unfortunately. :(
@Avatar

Comment: @Michael I spent too long time to fix this but I was not able to find a way :( Hoping community will.

Comment: I dont have much points but we can try to start a bounty. @Michael

Comment: @Avatar - Me either, but I'll be happy to contribute in any way I can. 
I also left a reply on the original blog that EFeit linked to.

Answer (score 3):

You think the disk space is allocated contiguously? You may think only the first 5GB is used. But the allocation can be all over the disk. It is your responsibility to copy the data to a smaller disk, attach it to your instance and discard the old disk. There are many tutorials on how to do it.

Comment: I have followed your guide and other answer's guide, but due to AWS system configurations, I was not able to fix the issue. Please see my updated answer. @helloV

Answer (score 1):

check this answer [here](https://serverfault.com/a/836600/431193), I has the same issue, and asked [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/872364/shrinking-ebs-volume-that-used-as-root).

I haven't tried the solution mentioned as I don't need this volume anymore and I was only concerned about the snapshot size, but it has been brought to my attention that the snapshot is stored as data based not block based so it won't reserve the same capacity as if it was live.

Comment: I have tried your first link, it did not work for me (Did it work for you?). After I have done everything till 17. step. But when I re-start the instance I have face with  "Error 15" on boot menu :( @Mahmoud Khateeb